# PHP display returned array values with print_r

Tags: php, arrays, calendar

I'm trying to use a date function I found on SO to create an array of dates from between two given dates. It looks like:

```
function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo) {
  // takes two dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD and creates an
  // inclusive array of the dates between the from and to dates.

  // could test validity of dates here but I'm already doing
  // that in the main script

  $aryRange=array();

  $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
  $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

  if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) {
    array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry

    while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) {
      $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
      array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
    }
  }
  return $aryRange;
}
$print_r($aryRange);
```

For some reason, it won't print the array. I know my `$strDateFrom` and `$strDateTo` values are good as I can echo them before and after the function. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Because you don't have $aryRange defined. It is a local variable within function which is never called. print_r(createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo))

Comment: You're doing it wrong...`$print_r($aryRange);` should be `print_r(createDateRangeArray('your start date', 'your end date'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign `$aryRange` to anything. The variable with this name within function is local and not the same as in print statement. You never call function, so never get the value from it.

Try this:

```
$strDateFrom = '2013-01-01';
$strDateTo = '2013-01-11';
$aryRange = createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo);
print_r($aryRange);
```